# Unable to import Fraction from fractions to virtual environment

Tags: python, virtual-environment, python-fractions

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
D:\_w\1\s\Modules\_decimal\libmpdec\context.c:57: warning: mpd_setminalloc: ignoring request to set MPD_MINALLOC a second time

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ldenn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\fractions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "C:\Users\Ldenn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\decimal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
  File "C:\Users\Ldenn\srv\Lproject\numbers.py", line 5
    >>> a = 14
    ^^
```

Comment: What if you run your REPL from somewhere other than `C:\Users\Ldenn\srv\Lproject` folder?

Comment: Is there a file named 'fractions.py' or some other python module name in your current working directory?

Comment: Works when I run it from one directory back, srv.  Both of you (@OneCricketeer and @alexpdev) are correct.  The virtual environment, Lproject, as I have it established does not support fractions.  Thanks!

Comment: The environment itself is fine. For example, activate it, back out of the folder, then run the script with the full path... You just cannot have other files named after Python builtin modules within your working directory or project since they will take precedence during import